# Adding watch to Python project in Debug mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am working in VSCode on Windows and have a created a debug configuration. I want to add a watch to inspect the contents of a data class as it is populated. My data class is setup like so:

```
class BSM:

    def __init__(self)
        self.ct = CTimer()

    def process(self, BP:float) -> None|CTimer:
        if .....
           self.ct = set_attribute1
```

If I just add `ct` or `self.ct` to the **Watch** window in VSCode I see nothing, yet my print(f"{self.ct}") shows data is in the CTimer dataclass instance ct.

What am I doing wrong, so that I can watch the instance self.ct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the field belonging to the instance of your class. If your instance is called `my_bsm`, you will then need to add `my_bsm.ct` to you Watch panel.

Comment: Tried that - didnt work. If my_bsm is a instance of other_class do I need to reference it like a path `other_class.my_bsm.ct` ?

Comment: yes, if `my_bsm` is a member of another class, you'll need to specify the entire path

Comment: I did try that too. Still just getting `not available` - will the watches show the contents while running or only when a breakpoint is hit? Because I am dealing with streamed data so breakpoints causes buffer overflows etc.

Comment: I see. Yes, the values get updated when a breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Bit this is streamed data. Will it work without breakpoint?

Comment: Unfortunately the watch panel is updated only after a breakpoint is hit. You can try using [logpoints](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_logpoints) instead.